# How to restore the backup from gitlab omnibus to gitlab when installed from source

Tags: backup, gitlab, restore, gitlab-omnibus

I have read the documentation about backup and restore gitlab but I have problem with my existing server when I have 1 server installed gitlab omnibus and 1 server gitlab installed from source.
It's possible to restore backup files from gitlab omnibus to gitlab when I installed from source ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Restoring backups is only supported for the same version as the backup was made for.
I fear the easiest solution is installing the original version, restoring the backup, then upgrading gitlab to the current version.